# Environments with matched parens in \begin and \end

Tags: environments

Suppose I have this sort of expression in a document.

```
\multicolumn{8}{l}{%
\parbox{25em}{%
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemsep}{-1em}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemize}%
}}
```

I'd like to define a new environment, call it "comment" that would allow me to simple write

```
\begin{comment}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{comment}
```

and produce the same output. The problem I've encountered is that the parentheses that are opened at the start are only balanced at the very end. That creates a problem if I try to define the "begin"-section of the new environment in the flatfooted way:

```
\newenvironment{comment}{%
  \multicolumn{8}{l}{%
  \parbox{25em}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \addtolength{\itemsep}{-1em}
}
```

The parentheses are unbalanced right now, and if I were to balance them inside the definition of the "begin" part of the environment, I'd get the wrong result.

Here's an MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}


\def\Boxes{%
  $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$%
}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccccccc}
    & Tue & Wed & Thur & Fri & Sat & Sun & Mon\\
    \hspace{1em}B$^{\flat}$ Major & \Boxes\\

    \multicolumn{8}{l}{%
      \parbox{25em}{%
      \begin{itemize}
        \addtolength{\itemsep}{-1em}
      \item foo
      \item bar
\end{itemize}%
}}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) which captures the contents of the environment in a macro `\BODY`. However, you need `\multicolumn` to be the first element in a cell. Can you show a use-case of your requirement in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)?

Comment: Just use the environment form of `\parbox` which is `minipage` then you can put `\begin{minipage}` in your start code and `\end{minipage}` in the code and so keep braces balanced. In the case of `multicolumn` use the `lrbox` environment as above to save the parbox and then use \multicolumn{}{..\usebox...}` in the end code to use the collected text.

Comment: As Werner said, you cannot hide `\multicolumn` inside the `\begin` part of an environment. It executes `\begingroup` quite at the beginning before the start code of the environment is executed. `\begingroup` destroys the possibility for `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Supplied an MWE. @DavidCarlisle, your suggestion is a little bit too telegraphic for me. Can you say more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments you can collect up the environment in `lrbox`. As noted in Werner's and Heiko's comments you can't use a standard `\begin` before `\multicolumn` so this fudges `\begin` slightly.

```
    \documentclass{article}
%! LaTeX Error: Command \Box not provided in base LaTeX2e.
% make supplied MWE processable, grumble
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\Boxes{%
  $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$%
}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\makeatletter
% only need this for \begin{spanlist} syntax otherwise skip this and use
% \spanlist....\endspanlist
\let\oldbegin\begin
\let\oldend\end
\def\begin#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\spanlist
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\oldbegin\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  \spanlist{#1}}
\def\end#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\spanlist
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\oldend\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  \endspanlist{#1}}
% end of scary \begin/\end redefinition.
\makeatother

\newenvironment{spanlist}
 {\omit\begin{lrbox}{0}\begin{minipage}{25em}\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{-1em}}
 {\end{itemize}\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \span\multicolumn{7}{l}{\usebox{0}}}

\begin{document}

% never use[h] on its own
%\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{table}[htp!]
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccccccc}
    & Tue & Wed & Thur & Fri & Sat & Sun & Mon\\
    \hspace{1em}B$^{\flat}$ Major & \Boxes\\
\begin{spanlist}
      \item foo
      \item bar
\end{spanlist}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```